# Playing a song using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, audio

I'm trying to play a song when the file receives a `'playMusic'` event from an Arduino, but I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined at EventSource.<anonymous>`. I've read that this could be because the audio is trying to play before the song file is ready, but combining the `window.onload` function in the event listener causes nothing to happen. I've added a delay of two seconds before I call the event to try to compensate for enough time to load the song file, but I still get the same error.

```
<html>
    <title>Song Time</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <body>
        <audio id="song">
            <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>

         <script type="text/javascript">
           var eventSource = new EventSource("https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/2d0024001047363330363431/events/?access_token=bdde583943e53ea709aa421a2e618d024700b2f1");

           eventSource.addEventListener('playMusic', function(e) {
                //window.onload=function() {
                    console.log("here");
                    $('song')[0].play();
                //}

           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
    at EventSource.<anonymous
```

Comment: `$(‘#song’)` you forgot #

Comment: your api isnt working for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @James

$(‘#song’) you forgot # – James

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like it's jQuery problem with this function, the funciton `play` is working fine with pure js.
here's the snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("play").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("play");
  document.getElementById("song").play();

});

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("stop");
  document.getElementById("song").pause();
  document.getElementById("song").currentTime = 0;

});

document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("stop");
  document.getElementById("song").pause();

});
```

```html
<html>
<title>Song Time</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<body>
  <audio id="song">
            <source src="http://www.cedarhome.org/mp3/songs/01%20Battlecry.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="play" id="play" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="pause" id="pause" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" /><br />
</body>

</html>
```